# Drupal Select option in form

Tags: php, sql, drupal

I am trying to create a select list in drupal that is populated from a custom table in my db.
The table consists of a name and an id number. They are both unique.

I used this to collect the data from the db and to populate two arrays.

```
$query = "SELECT `id`, title` from {svm_mail_esp}";
$result = db_query($query);
$i=0;
while($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
$listName[$i] = $row['title'];
$listID[$i] = $row['id'];
$i++;
}
```

Here is the $form array I used:

```
$form['esp_refferer'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => 'Service Provider',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#options' => $list, 
  '#cols' => 10,
  '#default_value' => '- Choose -', //TODO: This needs to be fixed and the form cannot be processed while this is selected
  '#multiple' => FALSE,
  );
```

This is where my problem is coming in, I want to display the name, but when the form is submitted I need the $node->esp_refferer to be the id number and not the name.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
   $list[$row['id']] = $row['title'];
}
```

You need to create an array $list, Keys of that array will be ids and value of each will be respective title.

Comment: So my array variable for #options would stay as list?
Im going to try that now. Thanks :)

Comment: Worked perfectly :) Thanks, you solved such a headache for me!!